# vb script convert csv to xls and set format of columns in xls file to be text

Tags: vba, csv, vbscript, xls

I am trying to create a vb script to convert a csv file to xls file.
The script I am using is:

```
Option Explicit
dim dtmToday,dtmDayOfWeek,objFSO,objArgs,i,CARF_STR_MGR,WSHSHELL,oExec,objStartFolder,objFolder,colFiles,objFile,wb
dim myXL,xl
Dim CSVfolder
Dim XlsFolder
Dim fname 
Dim WorkBooks


Const xlDelimited = 1
Const xlWorkbookNormal = -4143
Const xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote =  1
Const xlOpenXMLWorkbook          = 56


SET WSHSHELL = WSCRIPT.CREATEOBJECT("WSCRIPT.SHELL") 
Set objArgs=Wscript.Arguments 'create object
dtmToday=objArgs(0)
dtmToday=formatDate("%Y%m%d",dtmToday)
Wscript.echo dtmToday

objStartFolder="\\xxxxxxxx\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxxxx"

Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)

Set colFiles= objFolder.Files

For Each objFile in colFiles
if LCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile))="csv" AND instr(objFile.Name,dtmToday)<>0 Then


xl.Workbooks.OpenText objFile, , , xlDelimited _
    , xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote, True, False, False, False, False, True, _
    ",", Array(Array(1,2), Array(2,2), Array(3,2), Array(4,2), Array(5,2) _
    , Array(6,2), Array(7,2), Array(8,2), Array(9,2), Array(10,2), Array(11,2))
    Set wb = xl.ActiveWorkbook
    wb.SaveAs ="\\xxxxxxxx\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxxxx"& objFile.name &".xls", xlOpenXMLWorkbook, , , , False
    wb.Close
    xl.Quit

End if


   Next
   Set wb = nothing
   Set xl = nothing

  function formatDate(format, intTimeStamp)
    ......
  end function
```

The issue with this code is that I can't seem to modify a specific value of a column to be text so I have a value in one of the columns in the csv file which is 00000 and I need this value to stay the same. But instead is being converted as 0 in the xls file.
Is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: This isn't a coding issue, it's an Excel issue.  Change the column in excel to "text" instead of "general".  It's treating it like an integer, and there's no such integer as 000000.

Comment: This is a csv file that I need to convert to xls in the csv file the value is 0000 when I am converting though the value becomes 0

Comment: there has to be a way to specifically mention to the script please take this and read it as a text and copy it as it is

Comment: for example if I convert the csv manually using the excel way to import the text format and save as to xls then that specific value is read and imported as 0000 and not as 0.

Comment: In your code you're specify all columns as Text - that doesn't fix it?

Comment: this was another point I wanted to raise.

Comment: Even though I have specifically mention in the Array(1,2) parts that I want all of the fields to be read as text again the 0000 text value is moved as 0 in the xls converted file

Comment: anyone has any idea????